# WCF client binding to access https service. Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, wcf-binding

I need to create WCF client to connect service available via https. 
Current client configuration responsible for WCF looks like this:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="TestBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
<client>
   <endpoint address="https://address/etc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestBinding" contract="TestService.Test" name="TestName"/>
</client>
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an error:

```
Exception: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException
Message: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'address'.
Source: mscorlib

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
...

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

I don't have an access to modify anywise this service

**UPDATE:**

For testing purpose I'm ignoring certificates in global.asax in Application_Start but I'm stil getting the same exception

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an Untrusted certificate can cause this.
try this before calling your service:

```
protected void BypassCertificateError()
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
}
```

but be aware that this is not a good practice as it completely ignores the server certificate.

Comment: I have this before calling, I had also in in ApplicationStart but still getting the same exception. 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

Comment: probably you are using WCFTestClient. unfortunately  WCFTestClient doesn't support Untrusted certificates. you can use SOAP UI in order to test your service.

Comment: I'm using client from code. It's generated by AddServiceReference. It's not wcftestclient

Comment: if its a public web service please provide a required information for calling your service. i hope i could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it's service available only inside my company

Comment: I'm sorry dear @Saint. all i can do is vote up your question and hope someone else help you.i also suggest to mention you are ignoring certificate on client side. good lock.